# Can use Integer is closed under subtraction without prove in Discrete Math?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

> Question

$ : ℤ × ℤ → ℤ, (, ) =  − n$

I need to prove this function is an onto function

> Attempts

I think I need to prove $m - n = y$ where $y ∈  ℤ$. Because I know Integer is closed under subtraction and that means an integer minus an integer must be an integer.
Is this enough to prove $m - n = y$ where $y ∈  ℤ$ and can prove $(, ) =  − n$ is surjective?

Comment: Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  You need to show that you can choose $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m - n = k$.  Hint:  Consider cases, depending on whether $k > 0$, $k = 0$, or $k < 0$.

Comment: But Integer is closed under subtraction, so I still need to prove it right? I think an integer minus an integer is an integer obviously.@N.F.Taussig

Comment: It is given that $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, so you do not need to prove the difference of two integers is an integer.  You just need to show that given $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exist $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m - n = k$.

Comment: but $m,n,k$ are all integers, and Z represents an integer, right? so, I think to prove m−n=k (k,m,n∈Z ) is as same as proving the difference of two integers is an integer.@N.F.Taussig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $f: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is defined by $f(m, n) = m - n$.  You are given that the domain is $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and that the codomain is $\mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, you know that the output is in the integers.  However, you must show that the range is equal to the codomain, that is, for each integer $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you must show that there exist integers $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m - n = k$.

**Hint:**  What happens if you let $n = 0$? $m = 0$?

Comment: If n = 0, k will equal m, and because k∈Z, then m∈Z ,yes. If If m = 0, k will equal -n, and because k∈Z, then -n∈Z ,yes. If both m,n=0, k will be 0.

Comment: Given $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we must show there exists $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(m, n) = m - n = k$.  Let $m = k$ and $n = 0$.  Then $f(m, n) = f(k, 0) = k - 0 = k$.  Hence, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: oops, I didn't understand you until now, I've got a lot to think this question

Comment: The key point here is that to show that a function $f: A \to B$ is surjective, you must show that for each $b \in B$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Comment: yes, I totally agree with you. But in this case, there are two variables m and n, not like the normal one, there only needs to prove some a∈A such that f(a)=b., and I get confused.